# I'm getting an error while creating cog in Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Code:

```
cogdeneme  = {
    "XIORXA BOT.örnekcog",
}
for x in cogdeneme:
    try:
        client.add_cog(x)
    except:
        print(x + "  <<== Something went wrong.")
```

weather.py dosyası:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
class deneme(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.command
    async def deneme(self,ctx):
        ctx.send("hello")
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(deneme(client))
```

as soon as i start it i get the message "An error has occurred" does anyone know why?

Comment: How did you organized your files ?

Comment: also its, `@commands.command()`

Comment: Edited Files As In Video, but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have permission to comment yet, so I'm going to type it here.

Did you define your bot? for example, client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description='- shows this message', intents=intents)?